# Verifying an object exists Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

To verify if an object exists is this enough?

```
if (object) ...
```

Or do I have to do the following:

```
if (object != NULL) ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: the first line should work

Answer (score 1):

Neither verifies if an object exists. They check to see if the `object` pointer variable is pointing to anything or not.

The first is an acceptable and common form of the more explicit second form.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C common used `nil`. It means that your pointer point to nothing. So if you want check if pointed object exist you can do `if (obj != nil) { ... }`. Or simplify it to `if (obj) { ... }`. But you also can use `NULL` instead of `nil`, so both of your example do the same.

[There is](http://nshipster.com/nil/) a great article about this topic.

Also you should know that in Obj-C world you can send messages to `nil`. There is no NullPointerException, and code below do nothing:

```
UIView *view = nil;
[view removeFromSuperView];
```